# Map[Int, String] in Play framework template

Tags: java, templates, playframework-2.0

I'm using the Play 2.0.4 framework and I can successfully create a template that accepts a `Map[String, String]` template by putting this in the controller part:

```
Map<String, String> test = new HashMap<String, String>();
return ok(views.html.template.render(test));
```

and in `template.scala.html`:

```
@(map : Map[String, String])
```

However, if I change the first `String` to an `Int` (Integer in the controller part), I get this exception:

```
 error: method render in class template cannot be applied to given types;
```

Is it possible to define an Integer -> String mapping in the Play framework and if so, how can I achieve it?

**Edit:**
The exception occurs when I change the code in the controller to:

```
Map<Integer, String> test = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

And in the template to:

```
@(map: Map[Int, String])
```

Comment: do you mean change it to an `Integer`? Or did you define your own `Int` class?

Comment: Show how it looks after your changes.

Comment: @AramKocharyan, I changed it to an Integer, see my edit for clarification

Comment: Does the exception say anything more? It might be because the template wants `scala.Int`s, but you give it `java.lang.Integer`s. Or something about Scala's and Java's repsective `Map` types. The exception should probably tell you that. Anyway, what happens if you change the template signature to `Map[Integer, String]`?

Comment: @Carsten changing the template signature to `Map[Integer, String]` worked. Can you please put your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template, you specify that your `Map`'s keys are `scala.Int`s, but you give it a `Map` with `java.lang.Integer`s as keys.

The solution is to change the line in your template to

```
@(map: Map[Integer, String])
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code, the generated `render` method accepts a `Map<Object, String>`. Then, you can supply such a map.

There are automatic conversion helpers from Java to Scala (and from Scala to Java). I don't know if one could apply if this case to allow you having a `Map<Integer, String>` in the `render` method.